# Simple ajax call not working, but response is ok

Tags: jquery, ajax, sinatra

I'm struggling from 3 or 4 hours with jQuery and Ajax. I have a simple ajax call that must replace the HTML inside a  node.

The HTML is this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="notify">
   <!-- BEGIN NOTIFICATION DROPDOWN -->
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

And my jQuery ajax call is this

```
$(document).on("click", ".formato", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(this).data('format');
    var b = $(this).data('content');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/magazine/article',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            format: a,
            content: b,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#notify').replaceWith(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            //if fails      
        }
    });
});
```

I check Chrome debugger for XHR response and the response is ok: my Sinatra app return me the `<li>` element to place inside the `<ul>`. But nothing happen, also the console.log is not working.

I don't have any error in the js console.

Do you know what's happen?

Comment: Have you logged that the error callback is returning by chance?

Comment: I log the error and the error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

Comment: Ok, now I understand. jQuery think that my payload is json, and try to parse it. But is HTMLO so I have to declare datatype!!!

Answer (score 0):

don't use replaceWith, because it will replace your `ul` element by what you get in response (`li` in this case)  which is incorrect, use `html()` function  instead :

```
$('#notify').html(data)
```